# PHP :multi-language issue

Tags: php, multilingual

I am creating a multilingual site, language switcher loads needed language file but if the file doesn't contain the needed entry, it doesn't appear at all, even default array value is not visible.

I make translation like this:

```
$lang = "en";
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){ 
    $lang = $_GET['lang']; 
}
require_once("languages/lang_".$lang.".php");
```

Language array:

```
<?php echo $language["USERNAME"]; ?>
```

Language file with translation:

```
$language["USERNAME"] = "User name";
```

If language file doesn't include `$language["USERNAME"] = "User name"`; then nothing is showing at all. What I am trying to achieve is: if loaded language file doesn't contain the translation, then array should return the default value, example: `USERNAME`.

I did check if array key or value is available to show needed information, but seems check is done in loaded language file and if the language file is empty, then there is nothing to show. I just need to show default array value which is located in the main PHP file. If there is no translation for array

```
<?php echo $language["USERNAME"]; ?>
```

I want to echo value in brackets: `USERNAME`.

Comment: is there anything you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately have no idea from where to start.

Comment: Create a function in that pass your array's key, and check if this key exist in translation then return value from translation. otherwise return default.

Comment: I did this: <?php
    foreach($language as $key=>$value){
        if (empty($value)) {
            $empty = $value = $key;
            $language[$value] = ucfirst(strtolower($empty));
        }
    }
?>
But still if language file doesn't contain array value, in index php there is no translation, just empty...

Comment: use `array_replace` function to merge EN and OTHER language file arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to define a default language. 
In that case i choose English.

In your language files, try not define a variable, but return the translation array.

If you are using return keyword in language files you can have control about variables, so you can include multiple language files in your script.

> Language files

**lang_en.php**

```
<?php
   return [
       'username' => 'username'
   ];
```

the same way for the other language files.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$lang = "en" // that's default language key
$GLOBALS['defaultLanguage'] = require_once('lang_'.$lang.'.php');

if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
   $lang = $_GET['lang'];
}
$GLOBALS['language'] = include('lang_'.$lang.'.php');

if(!is_array($GLOBALS['language']) {
   $GLOBALS['language'] = [];
}
echo translate('username');
```

**translate function**

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @return string
 */
function translate($key)
{
    $language = $GLOBALS['language'];
    $defaultLanguage = $GLOBALS['defaultLanguage'];

    if(!isset($language[$key]) || !$language[$key]){
        $language[$key] = $defaultLanguage[$key];
    }


    return $language[$key];
}
```

Comment: Quick question: <?php echo $language["USERNAME"]; ?> will return nothing, but is there any simple way to return array main value (in this case word USERNAME) if there is no translation?

Comment: if `$language['username']` return null or is not set then the `username` value will be from default language. Just test the code above and you'll find how it is working.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. If language file is empty, just empty document without any translation, then I still see nothing.

Comment: i edited after i include the dynamic language file. `if(!is_array($language){$language = []; }`

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, nothing loaded, empty translation. I feel like no one understands what I am really asking :) Imagine that loaded language file is absolutely empty, then language entry <?php echo $language["USERNAME"]; ?> should show USERNAME or any other value which is present exactly in this object: <?php echo $language["SOMETHING_WHICH_MIGHT_HAVE_TRANSLATION"]; ?>

Comment: Did you change the structure of language files to use a return and not the language variable ?

Comment: Yep, finally works now. Also syntax error was here: if(!is_array($language) {... Thanx, works now as I wanted, but another thing, all text which should be translated looks like echo translate($defaultLanguage,$language,'text_which_will_have_translation')... It looks a big ugly with those variables $defaultLanguage,$language. Maybe there is other simplier way?

Comment: use the $GLOBALS var to store the language data. And i updated the post :)

Comment: Yes. it works perfectly, thank you. One more thing, is it possible to simplify syntax of language file to look like 'username' = 'User name', without return [ ]

Comment: in this way not, you must use an array.. That's the simplest way, a better way is to use `xliff` which is a `xml` format.. Just search by `xliff` language files on google

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161703/discussion-between-newcomer-and-andrei-todorut).

Answer (score 0):

Language array:

```
$language["USERNAME"] = "User name";
```

File Script

```
$lang = "en";
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){ 
    $lang = $_GET['lang']; 
}
require_once("languages/lang_".$lang.".php");
global $templang = $language;

<?php echo language("USERNAME"); ?>

funtion language($key){
    global $templang;
    return (isset($templang[$key]))? $templang[$key] : "Default Value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function getTranslatedText($key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array_contains_translation_text))
        return $array_contains_translation_text[$key];
    else
        return $array_contains_common_text[$key];
}


getTranslatedText("UserName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Andrei Todorut answer, you can simply merge 2 language files, replacing default strings with translated, where non-translated will remain untouched. To achieve this, you can use [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) function, that will do the trick. This will preserve your `$language` array, no extra functions needed to check for existence of translated string etc.

Let's assume your language file looks like this:

**lang_en.php**

```
<?php
  return [
   'username' => 'username',
   'no-trans' => 'not translated'
  ];
```

**lang_other.php**

```
<?php
  return [
   'username' => 'user name'
  ];
```

**Multilingual array code:**

```
<?php
  $lang = "en";
  $defaultLanguage = require_once('lang_'.$lang.'.php');

  if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
  }
  $translated = include('lang_'.$lang.'.php');

  if(is_array($translated)) {
    $language = array_replace($defaultLanguage, $translated);
  } else {
    $language = $defaultLanguage;
  }
```

**Output**

```
  print_r($language);
  // output:
  array[
    'username' => 'user name',
    'no-trans' => 'not translated'
  ]

  echo $language['username'];
  // output:
  user name
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after discussion with Newcomer and better understanding some requirements, here is another solution to the problem:

> Language files

**lang_en.php**

```
<?php
  $language["USERNAME"] = "Username";
  $language["EMAIL"] = "Email";
  $language["PASSWORD"] = "Password";
  $language["CREATE_ACCOUNT"] = "Create account";
```

**lang_de.php**

```
<?php
  $language["USERNAME"] = "Nutzername";
  $language["PASSWORD"] = "Passwort";
```

> Scripts and functions

**index.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('translate.php');
  if(isset($_GET['lang']) && file_exists('lang_'.$_GET['lang'].'.php')) {
    include_once('lang_'.$_GET['lang'].'.php');
  } else {
    include_once('lang_en.php');
  }

  // print
  _e('USERNAME');
  // return
  __('USERNAME');
```

**translate.php**

```
<?php
  function _e($key) {
    if(isset($language[$key])) {
      echo $language[$key];
    } else {
      echo $key;
    }
  }

  function __($key) {
    if(isset($language[$key])) {
      return $language[$key];
    } else {
      return $key;
    }
  }
```