# Why my multilanguage site in php doesn't work fine?

Tags: php, html, navigation, multilingual

I'm working on a PHP Website and I need to translate the pages in 4 different languages.

I was looking for an help and I found this post (the first answer): [PHP :multi-language issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904405/php-multi-language-issue/67531281#67531281)

I applied this code and it works on my home page but what about navigation?

If I select the second language and then go on menu voices (for example "who we are"), the page load with default language and not with the select language in home page.

The other pages are into folders as index.php.

How can I fix it?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The selected language needs to be remembered between page requests. This can be achieved in a few different ways. Some of those are:

1. Remember the selected language in a cookie;
2. Remember the selected language in the session;
3. Always append a `?lang=...` query param to each URL.

Comment: Hello Zoli, thank you for your answer! 

Ok, so I've to apply one of these 3 solutions.
 If I want to apply your third solution,  how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

hye,
I think that to keep the language selected you have to set cookies in javascript